# What is the string function in VB.Net for extracting a string that starts with a certain character and ends with a certain character?

Tags: vb.net, string, function

I have a string: **"*45%235?35"**. What i want is to extract the number strings from this one. So I will have **str1 = "45"**, **str2 = "235"** and **str3 = "35"**.

So what string function in VB.Net should i be using to extract strings that start from a certain character and ends with a certain character exclusive?Thank you

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: @MitchWheat I did look into string manipulation functions but could not find any that can fulfill my requirement. Do i need to write a procedure that would be using 2 or more string functions to satisfy my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficient way, pure string methods:

```
Dim str = "*45%235?35"
Dim str1, str2, str3 As String
Dim sIndex, eIndex As Int32
sIndex = str.IndexOf("*")
If sIndex >= 0 Then
    sIndex += 1
    eIndex = str.IndexOf("%", sIndex)
    If eIndex >= 0 Then
        str1 = str.Substring(sIndex, eIndex - sIndex)
        sIndex = eIndex + 1
        eIndex = str.IndexOf("?", sIndex)
        If eIndex >= 0 Then
            str2 = str.Substring(sIndex, eIndex - sIndex)
            str3 = str.Substring(eIndex + 1)  ' Take rest
        End If
    End If
End If
```

It works if the order is  always the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. Wonder if the same thing can be achieved by using regular expressions instead of string functions?

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: for sure, but regex are not my strong point and i've run out of time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with RegEX, you can modify the RegEx pattern "\D+" to eliminate the asterisk or simply ignore the first item in matchResults

```
    Dim regexObj = New Regex("\D+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim matchResults As String() = regexObj.Split("*45%235?35")
    For Each s As String In matchResults
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", s)
    Next
```